# How to filter data based on populated item's null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

[image]

I do have object. For example -

```
{ 
 active: true,
 category: { _id: 1212, name: 'something', active: false},
 name: "test",
}
```

My category object came from mongodb populated item. Now when I populated item I filtered it based on active=false. which returned null on category field.
For instance,

```
{ 
 active: true,
 category: null,
 name: "test",
}
```

Now my main focus is to remove this object if category is null.

I did use like this -

```
  match: { category: { $exists: true } },
  populate: "category"
```

but it doesn't work because initially category object exists. But after populate and based on active status it's became null.

So what is the best way to remove this object if category is null.

N.B: I know it will work using aggregate. But I do not use aggregate because the query is too long. I have to change many things if I do aggregate. And populate is multilevel. So it will be a problem.

Comment: Can you share your complete query and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are looking for a field that "exists" even though its value is null, the field is there.
You could just search for the null value and it should work.

```
 match: { category: null }
```

Comment: in generel, it is not null. but after populate its became null

Comment: I just changed your last query so you can find those null values. Was not that what you want?